# Get keyboard's input and count number of letters, digits and spaces in java

Tags: java, string

How to write a java program to get a string as a key board input. Then count the number of letters, digits and spaces available in that string and display the count of letters, digits and spaces.

Comment: hopefully this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832195/keypress-how-to-detect-if-the-user-pressed-the-down-arrow-key-on-their-keyboa) can help you

Answer (score 1):

This is honestly... really, really easy and something that really should be taught to you in an introductory course or something.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String userInput = scan.nextLine();
```

You will need to put, right after `package`, `import java.util.Scanner`. To do the other thing, i.e. counting the number of characters in the String, simply invoke `length()`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a string as an argument in this method you get count of letter, space, and digit

```
public void count(String str) {
        int space = 0;
        int digit = 0;
        int letter =0;
        for (int f4 = 0; f4 < str.length(); f4++) {
            if (Character.isSpace(str.charAt(f4))) 
            space++;
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(f4)))
                letter++;
            if(Character.isDigit(str.charAt(f4)))
                digit++;
        }
        System.out.println("space = "+space+", digit = "+digit+", letter = "+letter); 
    }
```